# Laravel Filament - Lost placeholder of my select when I reset it

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm using FilamentPHP and I come to you because I lose the placeholder of my select when I reset it. A video is much more telling:

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTwz.gif)

I'm using the layout (https://filamentphp.com/tricks/render-html-in-select-options) and haven't had any issues so far. It looks like there is a reload conflict between my selects.

A snippet of my code:

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('extendedProps.type_task_id')
    ->label('Type de tâche')
    //->required()
    ->allowHtml()
    ->searchable()
    // Chargement du formulaire au chargement
    ->options(function(Closure $get) {
        $types = collect([]);
        if(!empty($get('extendedProps.team_id'))) {
            $types = TypeTask::where('team_id', $get('extendedProps.team_id'))->get();
        }
        
        return $types->mapWithKeys(function ($type) {
            return [$type->getKey() => static::getSelectIcon($type)];
        })->toArray();
    })
    // Chargement du formulaire à la recherche
    ->getSearchResultsUsing(function (Closure $get, string $search) {
        $types = collect([]);
        if(!empty($get('extendedProps.team_id'))) {
            $types = TypeTask::where('team_id', $get('extendedProps.team_id'))
                ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->limit(50)
                ->get();
        }
        
        return $types->mapWithKeys(function ($type) {
            return [$type->getKey() => static::getSelectIcon($type)];
        })->toArray();
    })
    
    ->reactive()
    ->preload()
    
    ->columnSpan(12)
    // Modification après sélection
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Closure $set, Closure $get, $state) {
        if ($get('extendedProps.product_id') !== null) {
            $set('extendedProps.product_id', null);
        }
        if ($get('extendedProps.device_id') !== null) {
            $set('extendedProps.device_id', null);
        }
    })
    ->extraAttributes(['class' => 'coucou-test'])
    ->placeholder('Libre')
    ->hidden(function(Closure $get) {
        $types = collect([]);
        if(!empty($get('extendedProps.team_id'))) {
            $types = TypeTask::where('team_id', $get('extendedProps.team_id'))->get();
    
            if(count($types) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    
        return false;
    }),

Forms\Components\Select::make('extendedProps.product_id')
    ->label('Produit')
    ->required()
    ->allowHtml()
    ->searchable()
    // Chargement du formulaire au chargement
    ->options(function(Closure $get) {
        $products = collect([]);
        if(in_array($get('extendedProps.type_task_id'), [1, 2])) { // Brassage + Conditionnement
            $products = Product::where('is_crafted', 1)->get();
        }
        else { // Ou le reste
            $products = Product::where('is_crafted', 0)->get();
        }
        
        return $products->mapWithKeys(function ($product) {
            return [$product->getKey() => static::getCleanOptionStringProduct($product)];
        })->toArray();
    })
    // Chargement du formulaire à la recherche
    ->getSearchResultsUsing(function (Closure $get, string $search) {
        $products = collect([]);
        if(in_array($get('extendedProps.type_task_id'), [1, 2])) { // Brassage + Conditionnement
            $products = Product::where('is_crafted', 1);
        }
        else { // Ou le reste
            $products = Product::where('is_crafted', 0);
        }
        $products = $products->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->limit(50)
            ->get();
        
        return $products->mapWithKeys(function ($product) {
            return [$product->getKey() => static::getCleanOptionStringProduct($product)];
        })->toArray();
    })
    ->reactive()
    ->preload()
    ->columnSpan(6)
    ->hidden(function(Closure $get) {
        if($get('extendedProps.type_task_id') != null) {
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    ->placeholder('Libre'),
```

Apart from this layout defect, everything works as I wish. If you have any idea where is my problem? Any history of reset conflict? Got a choice.js issue? A problem loading HTML in my select like this is reset?

Good for you, Thank's.